# C++ random number -infinity to +infinity

Tags: c++, random

This is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    random2 = (1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX);

    if (random2 >= 0.5)
    {
        random = (1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX);
    }
    else {
        random = -(1.0 * rand() / RAND_MAX);
    }
}
```

I want to get a random number between -infinity and+infinity 10000 times.

I tries -1 between 1 to get a random number.
but I need -infinity between +infinity random number.
this is my best
please give me your wisdom

Comment: It's not possible to generate a uniform random number in an unbounded range ("between -infinity and +infinity").  By contrast, certain other distributions _are_ unbounded, such as the normal distribution.

Comment: Do you really need infinite limits? Using [std::uniform_real_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) would be simple if you had finite limits, you could even use [`std::numeric_limits<double>::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) which is `1e308`

Comment: what kind of distribution? Such range suggest something else then uniform distribution.

Comment: thank you! i need this code for random variable Gaussian distribution Is there any other way to make this code happen?

Comment: try [`std::normal_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

Since your computer does not have infinite memory, it cannot represent numbers infinitely large. You *must* settle for a range that's *finite*.

The floating point specification includes a pseudo "infinity" value that really just represents "too big to store in the current type", or as "larger than all other values". It's not literally infinity. It's effectively just the horizon on the range of defined numerical values.

You *could* theoretically write a function that returns values in the entire `double` numerical range, but that's far more complicated in practice than it might sound superficially. The numerical accuracy of floating point numbers declines as the magnitude grows larger, meaning it is impossible to have a *uniform distribution* of values across all allowed values. They will necessarily clump up.

It sounds like you need to explore the capabilities and limitations of both integer types and floating-point types to better understand how you might translate your requirements into something that makes sense with those concepts in mind.

Comment: thank you for your answer!! i'll study what you said